# BC30311 Visual Basic AND VB.NET Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'TextBox'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to transfer information from a text box from one form to another when a button is pressed but it's coming up with this error "BC30311 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'TextBox'." can anyone help me please. Code is below.

```
Private Sub BtnInvoice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInvoice.Click
        'Shows the Invoice form and transfers information into it'
        Invoice.Show()
        Invoice.TxtHours1 = TxtLabour.Text
        Invoice.TxtTravel1 = TxtTravel.Text
        Invoice.TxtPlastic1 = TxtPlastic.Text
        Invoice.TxtCopper1 = TxtCopper.Text
        Invoice.TxtChrome1 = TxtChrome.Text
        Invoice.TxtDiscount = TxtDiscount.Text
        Invoice.TxtTotal = TxtTotal.Text
```

Comment: You should give us some more info... like what is "Invoice", and what is of type string vs ... Anyways, I would first check object definition (as TextBox instead of string...  Plus, you should see how to bind object to forms and properties to controls...

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a string to TextBox, you need to set the Text property of the TextBox:

```
Private Sub BtnInvoice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInvoice.Click
        'Shows the Invoice form and transfers information into it'
        Invoice.Show()
        Invoice.TxtHours1.Text = TxtLabour.Text
        Invoice.TxtTravel1.Text = TxtTravel.Text
        Invoice.TxtPlastic1.Text = TxtPlastic.Text
        Invoice.TxtCopper1.Text = TxtCopper.Text
        Invoice.TxtChrome1.Text = TxtChrome.Text
        Invoice.TxtDiscount.Text = TxtDiscount.Text
        Invoice.TxtTotal.Text = TxtTotal.Text
```

Comment: @JLK please thank the poster by accepting the answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.